# How can I move a column to a new sheet once row 1 has a certain value?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, move

I am using the code posted here that moves a row based on the value of a column, but I want to edit it so that it does the opposite: moves a column to a new sheet based on the value of a row.
This is what I have so far:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // source data in sheet named Blocks
  // sheet column is moved to named Ordered
  // test row with word "Done" is row 1
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Blocks" && r.getRow() == 1 && r.getValue() == "Done") {
    var column = r.getColumn();
    var numRows = s.getLastRow();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Ordered");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastColumn() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(column, 1, 1, numRows).copyTo(target);
    s.deleteColumn(column);
  }
}
```

The problem is, when I tested it, it only moved the first row of that column. I want it to move the entire column and then delete it from the original sheet.

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. I find the question hard to understand. Please add some input data and the expected result to make it easier to understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Moving Selected Columns

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('Entry');
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Blocks" && e.range.rowStart == 1 && e.value == "Done") {
    //e.source.toast('Ordered1')
    var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Ordered");
    var target = tsh.getRange(1,tsh.getLastColumn() + 1);
    sh.getRange(2, e.range.columnStart, sh.getLastRow() -1).copyTo(target);
    sh.deleteColumn(e.range.columnStart);
  }
}
```

I used Active/Done datavalidation on row one and I only moved from row two to last row and then deleted the entire column including the validated cell.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly.